# Google analytics __utm gif request oddities

Tags: google-analytics

There are some strange variations that I'd like to understand what they are made for.

I couldn't find out there in the researches I did, so I came here as my last resource.
This is the list of things I'd like to understand:

1. Two different pages of mine, with the very same JS code snippet, call different URIs. The first one calls `https://ssl.google-analytics.com/r/__utm.gif` and the second one calls `https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif`. So what's the difference between the **/r/__utm.gif** and **/__utm.gif**?
2. What the parameter **utmht** is for?
3. What the parameter **utmjid** is for? The first URL has a big number value, which looks like an id, while the second one doesn't have any value for it.

I'm asking all this because I believe some of those variations might be making the second URL to not work in the end. Given the second URL is not producing entries (pageviews) in the GA admin pages.

Comment: I found out that it's not simple as I thought. If I do the other way around, by changing the order I request the pages, the situation also happens in reverse. But the first URL still gets in the statistics while the second one still doesn't get into the GA statistics. So the issue might be due to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the root cause of my problem.
The cause wasn't lying in the code.

The problem was that marketing team is using a View Filter with specific "Include" rules. And the page that wasn't getting in the statistics wasn't also included in that rule.

I'm not very familiar with all the features Google Analytics provides, so beware about these filter capabilities to avoid spending so much time in a silly thing like I did. :P